# Is it possible to pin a message using Telegram API?

Tags: telegram-bot

Is it possible to pin a message using the Telegram API? I would like to create a bot to pin messages in a chat group. I was unable to find an specific method to do it in the documentation:

```
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you should first turn off the group privacy mode of your bot in your BotFather panel.

then, your bot should be the admin of that chat in order to be able to pin messages.

finally, you can use [pinChatMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#pinchatmessage), [unpinChatMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#unpinchatmessage) to do the task.

Answer (score 0):

the code use `import telebot`

1. you need to make your bot admin an the group

   ```
   @bot.message_handler(commands=['pin'])
   def pin(message):
     message = bot.send_message('@username-for-you-group', 'Test!!')
     bot.pin_chat_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
   ```